# Response.Write--How to show Image

Tags: c#, image, response.write

This is my image Url

```
string fileUrl = file.Link;
```

I want to show this on Response.Write.How to do it?

```
Response.Write("<img src='" & fileUrl& "'/>")
```

Above Code I tried.But it doesn't work.

Comment: What is in the property `Link`?

Comment: @BlackFrog I'm taking image from an external site and file.Link returns ImageLink from external Site.I successfully stored the image on my local machine. But I need to show it in my project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And it was that &...
It works fine by replacing & with +..

```
Response.Write("<img src='" + fileUrl+ "'/>")
```

Answer (score 0):

let the `filePath` contain virtual address like shown

```
string filePath  = "http://localhost:2053/Styles/Images/myPersonalImage.jpg"
Response.Write("<img src='" & filePath & "'/>");
```

Comment: Image is not on local host.I'm taking it from an external site. I successfully stored the image on my local machine. But I need to show it in my project

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Server.MapPath.

```
string fileUrl = Server.MapPath(file.Link);
```

Comment: What should be inside Response.Write?